# Why does my script repeats the same email to the email address that is found on the first line?

Tags: google-apps-script, email, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a google apps script to send emails to every row of data that meets a certain criteria. It will also modify some of the data in the sheet as it passes through the script. However, my script repeats for the correct number of times, but it sends all the emails out to the email address in the first line of data.

I have tried changing where i store the variable as i believe it is the reason why the var emailAddress is not updating as the for loop runs. However, i cannot seem to figure out exactly why the var does not update to the next row of data.

```
 var header = "**Please show this email during collection.\n\n"

function sendEmails2() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var startRow = 2;
 var numRows = 500;
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 500); // (startRow, 'first row of column to process', numRows, 'number of columns to process')
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
   var row = data[i];
   var invoiceNum = row[2];
   var orderNum = row[3];
   var emailAddress = row[5];
   var orderStatus = row[9];
   var dispatchMode = row[11];
   var message = "Dear Customer, \n\nYour order is ready for collection.\n\n";
   var emailSent = row[19];
   var date = new Date;
   var title = "Order Ready";
   var header = "**Please show this email during collection.\n\n";
   var footer = "This is a System Generated email. Please do not reply to this email."
   if (emailSent == '' && orderStatus == 'Stock' && dispatchMode == 'Collection' && orderNum != ''){
     var subject = 'Prints Ready (Invoice No. ' + invoiceNum + '/Order No. E' + orderNum + ')';
     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue('Office');
     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 20).setValue(EMAIL_STATUS);
     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 21).setValue(date);
     this.sendgrid();
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   }
   else if (emailSent == '' && orderStatus == 'Stock' && dispatchMode == 'Collection' && orderNum == ''){
     var subject = 'Prints Ready- (Invoice No. ' + invoiceNum + ')';
     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue('Office');
     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 20).setValue(EMAIL_STATUS);
     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 21).setValue(date);
     this.sendgrid();
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   }
 }
}


function sendgrid() {
 var SENDGRID_KEY ='*****';
 var headers = {
   "Authorization" : "Bearer "+SENDGRID_KEY, 
   "Content-Type": "application/json" 
 }
 var body =
 {
 "personalizations": [
   {
     "to": [
       {
         "email": emailAddress
       }
     ],
     "subject": title
   }
 ],
 "from": {
   "email": "noreply@*****.com"
 },
 "content": [
   {
     "type": "text",
     "value": header + message + footer
   }
 ]
}
 var options = {
   'method':'post',
   'headers':headers,
   'payload':JSON.stringify(body)
 }
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",options);
Logger.log(response);
}
```

All the emails for the entire loop ends up being sent to the email address in the first row of data instead of its respective rows.

Comment: Why don't you provide the email address as a parameter to the sendgrid function? That would make the function a lot more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem is the way how you use `this`.

It will be much easier if you don't use `this` at all, but

- Define constant variables like `message`, `date`, `title`, `header` and `footer` one single time outside the function, rather than redefining them in every loop
- Define `sendgrid` as `function sendgrid(emailAddress) {...}` and call it within the `for` loop with the email retrieved during each iteration `sendgrid(emailAddress);` instead of `this.sendgrid();`

**Other small issues with your code:**

1. You define `header` twice
2. Instead of using `this.sendgrid(); SpreadsheetApp.flush();` two times - both in `if` and `else` statements - you can use it a single time after those statements